# Got problem converting string to upper case letters

Tags: c++

Using following console application i am converting each string to uppercase letters. But string value in output remains unchanged. what I am doing wrong here. Also any help on doing this efficiently would be appreciated.Thanks for your help.

```
int main()
{    

    vector<string> svec, svec_out;
    string word;
    int run;

    cout << "Press 0 to quit giving input string" << endl;

    while(1)
    {
        cin >> word;
        svec.push_back(word);

        cin >> run;
        if (!run)
            break;
    }

    cout << "converting to upper case... " << endl;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i!=svec.size(); ++i)
    {
        word = svec[i];
        for (string::size_type j=0; j < word.size(); ++j)
        {
            toupper(word[j]);
        }

        svec_out.push_back(word);
    }


    for ( i = 0; i<svec_out.size(); i++)
        cout << svec_out[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`toupper` will return the uppercase value instead of modifying the value in-place. As such your code should read:

```
word[j] = toupper(word[j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple reminder (more than an answer): calling ::toupper with
a type char is undefined behavior (even if most implementations
try to make it work most of the time).  The global ::toupper
function requires an int in input, and that int must be in the
range [0, UCHAR_MAX] or be equal to EOF (usually -1).  If plain
char is signed (the most frequent case), you will end up calling
::toupper with negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the problem. miss the toupper() method's return value

Comment: Then you should accept the answer that helped you (or this one, if you worked it out by your very own self).

Comment: @Johnsyweb: As new to stackoverflow I am still learning it's feature.Thanks for pointing it to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assign the toUpper value to your word

```
word[j] = toupper(word[j]);
```

That should do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::transform` as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
   std::string s="nawaz";
   std::string S;
   std::transform(s.begin(),s.end(), std::back_inserter(S), ::toupper);
   std::cout << S ;
}
```

Output:

```
NAWAZ
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/WtbTI

Comment: Isn't toupper() in the std namespace when you include <cctype>? Mind you it compiles for me too. I was just thinking out loud.

Comment: @Martin: Previously I had written `std::toupper`, but it didn't compile. But when I removed the `std::`, to my surprise it gets compiled. So I've the same doubt as you do!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
transform(svec[i].begin(), svec[i].end(), svec[i].begin(), toupper);
```

Answer (score 0):

I bid for the shortest bit of code:

```
 #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

 boost::to_upper(svec);
```

You can find many more in [Boost String Algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo.html), `[to_upper][2]` modifies the string in place and also features a `to_upper_copy` cousin, which returns a (transformed) copy and leaves the original string untouched.

Answer (score 0):

kinda outdated but you can change:

```
for (string::size_type j=0; j < word.size(); ++j)
    {
        toupper(word[j]);
    }
```

to:

```
for (auto &j : word) // for every j in word (note j is a reference)
    j=toupper(j);   // replace that j with it's uppercase
```

Just learned this stuff from C++ Primer - Part I - chapter 3